# unchecked remember me functionality

Tags: authentication, session

I have a website with jwt and refresh tokens. The jwt has a very short lifetime, something like 5 minutes and the refresh token lifetime is set to something like 6 months when the remember me is checked.

I want to know what is the best solution for when the remember me is unchecked. Should the refresh token simply have a shorter lifetime? Like a few hours? Or maybe on leaving the website I should clear the local storage with the jwt/refresh token data? Is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your refresh token should be configured as the maximum intended lifetime of the user's session. When they don't want to be remembered, this should mean:

- Any cookies your app/server creates should be session cookies
- When the user explicitly logs out, the user's session should be fully
  cleared
- Your refresh tokens should last as long as a standard user
  session, eg. for business apps, the length of a standard business day
  (12 hours)

Comment: but if I use session cookies, to my knowledge, if they open a new tab, they'd need to login again.
*Edit: Doesn't seem like normal behavior.

Comment: that's not correct - session cookies are persisted across the entire browser session, including multiple tabs. they are only removed when the browser itself is closed, or all tabs are closed - depending on the browser's behaviour.